# How to get period when data is loaded to stop shimmer?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, shimmer

I am using Volley for requests and want to add shimmer while data is loading. I can perform it with Handler but I don't know when data will come and can't set exact time.

Here is code in my Fragment. I want to set value `false` to  variable `isShimmer` and it makes so fast so my shimmer is not running:

```
String url = "my_url";
JsonArrayRequest getArticleOfTheDayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject articleObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        int article_id = articleObject.getInt("article_id");
                        String title = articleObject.getString("title");
                        String text = articleObject.getString("text");
                        ArticleOfTheWeek articleOfTheWeek = new ArticleOfTheWeek(article_id, title, text);
                        articleOfTheWeekList.add(articleOfTheWeek);
                    }
                    articleOfTheWeekAdapter = new ArticleOfTheWeekAdapter(getContext(), articleOfTheWeekList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(articleOfTheWeekAdapter);
                    articleOfTheWeekAdapter.isShimmer = false;
                    articleOfTheWeekAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            },
            error -> Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage() + " ")
    );
```

Here code in my adapter:

```
public boolean isShimmer = true;
int shimmerNumber = 2;

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArticleOfTheWeekViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ArticleOfTheWeek articleOfTheWeek = articleOfTheWeekList.get(position);

        if(isShimmer)
        {
            holder.shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        }else
            {
            holder.shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
            holder.shimmerFrameLayout.setShimmer(null);

            holder.textViewTitle.setBackground(null);
            holder.textViewTitle.setText(articleOfTheWeek.getTitle());
            holder.textViewDesc.setBackground(null);
            holder.textViewDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(articleOfTheWeek.getText()));
        }

    }
```

As you see if I set `isShimmer` true, shimmer runs infinite. So I can't get a period when all data is loaded to change value of `isShimmer`

Comment: Any specific reason why you are showing and stopping shimmer in `adapter`?

Comment: @RahulGaur sorry? Where should i use shimmer?

Comment: You can also update shimmer in `JsonArrayRequest`, show and hide shimmer in your Json response, show before json request, hide when you receive data in your response

Comment: how?  I didn't get it

Comment: Your solution is too helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [this](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android) library for show shimmer effect while fetching data. First set visibility true to your shimmer layout in your xml file then start shimmer on the start of the activity `shimmerViewContainer.startShimmer()`.

Set `shimmerViewContainer.stopShimmer()` in your volley method after set data to your adapter in activity file.

As well as stop shimmer on `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`

Comment: I am using this library too. But it's already set after setting data to adapter, no?

Comment: Not in adapter but when you are setting data to your adapter in activity file.

Comment: i.e   recyclerView.setAdapter(articleOfTheWeekAdapter);
shimmerViewContainer.stopShimmer();
shimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Hmm... take me some time to check it

Comment: Should I declare a shimmer from the outside? My shimmer declared in my file i.e. article_of_the_day.xml

Comment: Declare shimmer in your java activity file.

Comment: Great to hear that:)

Answer (score 0):

May be it would be easier for you to maintain the shimmer state if you put the shimmer in the parent layout rather than within the adapter layout. I would prefer below approach:

---

**1. Inside the layout of Activity/Fragment**

```html
<RelativeLayout>
 <RecyclerView/>
 <FrameLayout 
  android:id="@+id/shimmer_container"> 
 <!-- show hide this FrameLayout container depend on state of data loading/loaded -->
 
  <include layout="@layout/list_shimmer"/>
 </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The **list_shimmer** may be looks like:

```html
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:shimmer_auto_start="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/just_like_adapter_item_layout" />

        <include layout="@layout/just_like_adapter_item_layout" />

        <!-- repeat until it's enough to fill the screen -->
    </LinearLayout>
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

The important property:

> **app:shimmer_auto_start="true"**

So you don't need to start the shimmer programmatically.

---

**2. Activity/Fragment**

```js
void initList(List<Data> items) {
  adapter.setItems(items);
  shimmer_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: You can take the shimmer out from ViewHolder and just load the data normally

Comment: based on your current code, simply replace **articleOfTheWeekAdapter.isShimmer = false;**  with **shimmer_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);**  after takeout the shimmer from your adapter